# How to know if someone has decrypted my encrypted drive?

Tags: encryption, decryption

My laptop was stolen a few weeks ago, I got it back and my drive was encrypted. How can I be sure it wasn't decrypted and the data accessed during this time? I thought about checking the timestamps of last opened/modified, but as I understand they could have been manually reverted back after opening.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way of knowing that the disk was *not* accessed and decrypted.

As you said, *if* the disk content was changed, this would prove it *had* been accessed logically (and, hence, decrypted).

But what if the content did *not* change?

When attempting to perform decryption (or any kind of forensic analysis) on a disk, the first stage involves *cloning* it onto a new hard disk, and operating on the copy. So the only change in the original hard disk is a bit more wear and tear, which can be accessed through the SMART interface - but to check it reliably you need to have a SMART status save from immediately before the theft and another to compare taken immediately after recovery.

This could supply a negative proof (i.e., if the "Power On Hours" counter had *not* increased, the disk was not powered on and so we know it cannot practically have been copied.

But if the counter went up, this only proves that the hard disk was powered on, *not* that it was read. The "Read Data Counter" is not available on all hard disks). Of course, power on time gives an idea of how much data *could* have been transferred (but, again unfortunately, this counter usually has a granularity of one hour. In one hour, much could have been copied).

To sum it up:

```
Observation                            Decrypted?
=================================================
SMART power-on count (POC) unchanged   SURELY NOT
SMART POC increase, read count unchg.  SURELY NOT
...
...   (a vast area in between)         WHO KNOWS?
...
Logical disk content changed           SURELY YES
```

However, disk-level encryption (VeraCrypt, BitLocker, etc.) is usually *very* secure, so unless you left the password accessible, I would not worry too much.

Comment: Pedantic Nit - It is possible to know it was decrypted or accessed, it's just not possible to know it wasn't. The latter question was doubtless the intended question as you recognized. *I think I've been cooped up too long.*